# How is ExtraTrees different from Decision Tree for classification of dataset with one feature?

Tags: classification, scikit-learn

From what I understand ExtraTrees has one source of randomness in building an ensemble - random selection of features. But if there is only one feature, shouldn't ExtraTrees be the same as a DecisionTree? The answer seems to be no according to my little experiment using sklearn. One explanation I can think of is that there's another source of randomness that I am not aware of

```
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
from sklearn.ensemble import ExtraTreesClassifier
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X, y = make_classification(n_samples=1000,
                           n_features=1,
                           n_informative=1,
                           n_redundant=0,
                           n_repeated=0,
                           n_classes=2,
                           random_state=0,
                           n_clusters_per_class = 1,
                           shuffle=False)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.33, random_state=42)
clf1 = ExtraTreesClassifier(n_estimators=25,random_state=11)
clf2 = ExtraTreesClassifier(n_estimators=1000,random_state=13)
clf3 = ExtraTreesClassifier(n_estimators=1,random_state=14)
clf4 = DecisionTreeClassifier(random_state = 15)
clf5 = DecisionTreeClassifier(random_state = 16)

models = [clf1,clf2,clf3,clf4,clf5]
for model in models:
  model.fit(X_train,y_train)
scores = list(map(lambda xx: xx.score(X_test,y_test), models))
for count,score in enumerate(scores,1): print('clf' + str(count),score, sep = ':')
#DecisionTree returned the same score regardless of the random state
#ExtraTrees with a really high number of estimators (e.g. 1000) returned the same score as Decision Tree regardless of random state
#ET with low number of estimators sometimes return a different score as Decision Tree regardless of random state - shouldn't ET with 1 estimator be the same as DT???

#output prints:
clf1:0.9454545454545454
clf2:0.9424242424242424
clf3:0.9484848484848485
clf4:0.9424242424242424
clf5:0.9424242424242424
```

Comment: There is also randomness in choosing a split point for a variable.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how that differs between an estimator in ET (e.g. a DT weak learner) and DT by itself?